# Not able to create a file with required bytes

Tags: c, linux, unix

I would like to create a file of specified bytes, but when bytes > buf_size the file is not created.
Could anyone help me solve this issue.Thanks.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    int i = 0;
    int fd;
    int bytes;
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size] = {' '};
    ssize_t wlen = 0;

    if (argc != 3)
        error(1, errno, "Too many or less number of arguments\n");
    file = argv[1];
    fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
    printf("The value of the file descriptor is : %d\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error in opening the file\n");
    printf("Successfully opened the file\n");   
    bytes = atoi(argv[2]);

    while (1) {
        wlen = write(fd, buf, bytes);
        if (wlen == -1) 
            error(1, errno, "Error in writing the file\n");
        bytes = bytes - wlen;
        if (bytes == 0)
            return 0;
    }
    if(close(fd) == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error in closing the file\n");

}
```

Comment: Please explain which error you're getting. It'll be helpful to us to answer you.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: `if (argc != 3)  error(1, errno, "Too many or less number of arguments\n");` ?!! At this point, `errno` is unspecified, and even if it were specified this error message should not depend on it.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from `buf_size` not being defined, you have to limit the "chunk" size to `buf_size`.

Here's a refactored version of your code that fixes the problem [along with some other errors]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

#define buf_size    100

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //int i = 0;
    int fd;
    int bytes;
    char *file;
    char buf[buf_size] = { ' ' };
    ssize_t wlen = 0;

    if (argc != 3)
        error(1, errno, "Too many or less number of arguments\n");

    file = argv[1];
    // NOTE/BUG: with O_CREAT, you have to supply the mode
    // NOTE/BUG: you should probably add O_TRUNC because if you run the
    // program twice, once with length of (e.g.) 5000 and then 300, the
    // file is _not_ shortened the second time
#if 0
    fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
#else
    fd = open(file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644);
#endif
    printf("The value of the file descriptor is : %d\n", fd);
    if (fd == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error in opening the file\n");
    printf("Successfully opened the file\n");

    bytes = atoi(argv[2]);

#if 0
    while (1) {
        wlen = write(fd, buf, bytes);
        if (wlen == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error in writing the file\n");
        bytes = bytes - wlen;
        if (bytes == 0)
            return 0;
    }

#else
    for (;  bytes > 0;  bytes -= wlen) {
        wlen = bytes;
        if (wlen > buf_size)
            wlen = buf_size;

        wlen = write(fd, buf, wlen);
        if (wlen == -1)
            error(1, errno, "Error in writing the file\n");
    }
#endif

    if (close(fd) == -1)
        error(1, errno, "Error in closing the file\n");

    return 0;
}
```